# How to prevent TPUEstimator from using GPU or TPU

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I need to force TPUEstimator to use the CPU. I have a rented google machine and the GPU is already running training. Since the CPUs are idle, I want to start a second Tensorflow session for evaluation but I want to force the evaluation cycle to use CPUs only so that it does not steal GPU time.

I am assuming there is a flag in the run_config or similar for doing this but am struggling to find one in the TF documentation.

```
run_config = tf.contrib.tpu.RunConfig(
    cluster=tpu_cluster_resolver,
    master=FLAGS.master,
    model_dir=FLAGS.output_dir,
    save_checkpoints_steps=FLAGS.save_checkpoints_steps,
    tpu_config=tf.contrib.tpu.TPUConfig(
        iterations_per_loop=FLAGS.iterations_per_loop,
        num_shards=FLAGS.num_tpu_cores,
        per_host_input_for_training=is_per_host))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run a TPUEstimator locally by including two arguments: (1) `use_tpu` should be set to `False`, and (2) `tf.contrib.tpu.RunConfig` should be passed as the `config` argument.

```py
my_tpu_estimator = tf.contrib.tpu.TPUEstimator(
    model_fn=my_model_fn,
    config=tf.contrib.tpu.RunConfig()
    use_tpu=False)
```

The majority of example TPU models can be run in local mode by setting the command line flags:

```
$> python mnist_tpu.py --use_tpu=false --master=''
```

More documentation can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_tpu#running_a_tpuestimator_locally).